# Php PDO want to fetch values from 2 columns and create array (one column value as key another as array)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, key

Mysql table is like this

```
NumberRenamed | CompanyName
---------------------
 1            | a
 2            | aa
 3            | z
```

`$_POST['transaction_partner_name']` includes 2 values, for example `a` and `z`

Need result like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [3] => z
)
```

Tried this

```
foreach($_POST['transaction_partner_name'] as $i => $post_transaction_partner_name) {
$placeholders .= '?,';
}
$placeholders = (rtrim( ($placeholders), ',' ));

try {
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT CompanyName, NumberRenamed 
  FROM 2_1_transactionpartners WHERE CompanyName IN ($placeholders)");
$stmt->execute( ($_POST['transaction_partner_name']) );

$stmt->bindColumn('CompanyName', $company_name);
$stmt->bindColumn('NumberRenamed', $number_renamed);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
$result = compact("number_renamed", "company_name");
//$result = $company_name. $number_renamed;
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
}

}
```

But get

```
Array
(
[number_renamed] => 1
[company_name] => a
)
```

or `a1` with `$result = $company_name. $number_renamed;`

Tried also this

```
$arraytable = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
$arraytable[$row['NumberRenamed']] = $row['CompanyName'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arraytable);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

but get

```
 Array
 (
     [] => 
 )
```

Please advice what need to correct

**Update**

After `$stmt->bindColumn('NumberRenamed', $number_renamed);`

Tried

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND)) {
$result = compact("number_renamed", "company_name");
$result[$row['number_renamed']] = $row['company_name'];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
```

Get

```
Array
(
    [number_renamed] => 1
    [company_name] => a
    [] => 
)
1
```

Then tried

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$row['number_renamed']] = $row['company_name'];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
```

And get

```
Array
(
    [] => 
)
1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your first code like this:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $result[$row['number_renamed']] = $row['company_name'];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($result), '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But somehow can not get it to work. Posted results in question after Update

Comment: Changed to `$result[$row['NumberRenamed']] = $row['CompanyName'];` and works. Only instead of one array, get multiple arrays (will experiment and change)

Answer (score 11):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT NumberRenamed, CompanyName FROM 2_1_transactionpartners WHERE CompanyName IN ($placeholders)");

$array_indexed_by_NumberRenamed = $db_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```